# Creating and handling an app timeout in Android

Tags: java, android

I was wondering what would be the best way to handle an application timeout, such as PayPal. I want the user to select between 1, 5, or 15 minute timeout period, so when they open up the application they would have to log in again.

My onResume method:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {

    }
```

It has nothing in it. But it crashes.

As a note: my app has two activities. The first activity is a login screen. The second activity is the main screen. The onResume method is in the second activity.

Comment: What have you tried? Knowing what methods you've used so far will help us determine the best fit for you.

Comment: If the authentication is based on HTTP transport (a android client - http server communication), then it is better to manage session timeout at http level (via http API like HttpClient), rather than in your Appilication's UI level.

Comment: I have only tried one method, and that's to have one starting "routing" activity. It will route you to the proper screen depending on how long you have been away from the app. Also, in response to yorkw, this app is totally local, no outside connections.

Comment: This will crash because you aren't calling super.onResume()

Comment: I changed it to `public void super.onResume()` but I get a red line under `super.onResume`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this in one of my apps:

You need a base Activity for which all of your activities will extend from. In this base activity, add a variable that keeps track of the 'last user activity' timestamp. In my case, user activity simply means they touch the screen. So override the dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) method, and set the 'last user activity' to current timestamp.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    lastActivity = new Date().getTime();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Then in onResume() method of this base activity, just compare current timestamp with 'last user activity' timestamp. If it more than either 1, 5 or 15 minutes (configurable by user), then launch another activity to ask the user to login.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - lastActivity > xxxx) {
       // startActivity and force logon
    }
}
```

Comment: I added `dispatchTouchEvent` and I added the `onResume` method. But, my app is creashing. I put a toast in the if statement. My error message seems to be `RuntimeException: Unable to Resume Activity`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your onResume() method, and indicate which line it crashed?

Comment: Your onResume() method has no super.onResume().

Comment: I added super.onResume() but I get a red line under it in eclipse.

Comment: super.onResume() should go inside the function public void onResume() { }

Comment: Couldn't perfect your method, but still trying it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a heartbeat timer while the app is running and active and keep track of the current time (or last activity time - either one). When the app goes into the background from the user hitting the home button (or exits - not sure how you handle the back button) - remember the value by saving it to shared preferences. When the app starts or resumes you can compare the current time to the saved time and if the delta is more than "x" then you can direct the user to a login screen. Make sure you are paying attention to onPause, onResume, onStop, onDestroy events in your main activity. I would personally user System.currentTimeMillis for the timestamp and then compare the millis and divide appropriately based on your time (seconds, minutes, etc.).