# How to set session timeout for my android application

Tags: android, session-timeout

In my application, sometimes after clicking on an activity, It keeps displaying the message "Loading", What could be the reason behind it??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and handling an app timeout in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496083/creating-and-handling-an-app-timeout-in-android)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "session" in this context.

Comment: What I am looking for is if the user is not interacting with the app for a specific time, then he shout automatically be logged out and sent to login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can has a task that checks periodically if your user hasn't interacted with the device or not.

and you can detect user interaction with the device using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()) method.

Activity.onUserInteraction(), which notifies you that the user has interacted with the screen somehow .. you can put it in a parent Activity class and have all your activities extend it.